# Inserting a variable in to a formula

Tags: excel, vba, variables, excel-formula

I am trying to insert a variable into a formula that i will be inserting into a table. The formula is supposed to perform a sumproduct from another table. I would normally just call out the table name but the problem is this will be run different times on different tables so it will never actually be the same table name.
I replaced the table name with the variable "PrevSh"

This formula below is whats in my macro. Its giving me issues. Its giving me Application-defined or object defined error.

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(A7<>"",SUMPRODUCT(('[" & PrevSh & "] !$D$4:$D$485=A7])*('[" & PrevSh & "] !$E$4:$E$485])),"")"

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim TableName As String
Dim theTable As ListObject
Dim PrevSh As String

  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  TableName = ActiveSheet.Previous.Name & "_Spider"
  PrevSh = ActiveSheet.Previous.Name
  Sheets.Add.Name = (TableName)

Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MATERIAL"
Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "TOTAL"
Range("C3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "QTY OF LNG"
Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MATERIAL DESCRIPTION"
Range("E3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "RAWMATERIAL LENGTH"
Range("F3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PIECES"
Range("A3:f4").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$3:$F$4"), , xlYes).Name = _
   TableName
Range(TableName & "[TOTAL]").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(A7<>"",SUMPRODUCT(('[" & PrevSh & "] !$D$4:$D$485=A7])*('[" & PrevSh & "] !$E$4:$E$485])),"")"
```

Comment: Double-up on the internal double quotes.

Comment: or just use chr(34) for quotes.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your formula.

1. Unmatched brackets []
2. Double quotes need to be prefixed with a double quote
3. FormulaR1C1 requires R1C1 format
4. Sheet name has extra brackets and '

Here is how you can fix it:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(A7<>"""",SUMPRODUCT((" & PrevSh & "!$D$4:$D$485=A7)*(" & PrevSh & "!$E$4:$E$485)),"""")"
```

---

If your curious about how to use the Chr(34) ascii value as @Sorceri suggested try this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(A7<>" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",SUMPRODUCT((" & PrevSh & "!$D$4:$D$485=A7)*(" & PrevSh & "!$E$4:$E$485))," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
```

---

Either way the result in your cell will be this (substitute your sheet name, I tested with sheet1):

```
=IF(A7<>"",SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$D$4:$D$485=A7)*(Sheet1!$E$4:$E$485)),"")
```